# codeigniter db function db->set() cant use with select?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i been wondering is it possible to use db->set() after db->select() in codeigniter framework?

been searching for awhile now, but all i found , implementation of db->set() for update and insert only..

Here is what i tried to do...

```
$this->db->select(" '1' AS id,MsMShipNo,date(AppDate) AS AppDate");
$this->db->from("Mailbox");
        
$this->db-set("id", "'id'+ 1", FALSE);
$this->db->limit(700);
```

my code is suppose to add increment variable (bil.)

thank you in advance.

### EDITED

> thank for all response.
>
> actually i want to write code like this using set in codeigniter.
>
> to get row number of numbering. these data will be sent as json.

```
set @rownum := 0;

select name,
  @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
from your_table
order by name
```

Comment: $this->db->set typo

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? In the context of a select what you show makes not sense.

Comment: are you trying to select or update? cause set() in select doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**

Thanks @DFriend for mentioning.

set() has no impact on select statement.

Comment: `set()` has no impact on a select statement in CI. The typo doesn't matter the values from `set()` ain't going to be included in the query that gets run.